# Spring Batch Admin ... Problems Building 1.3.0 RELEASE

Tags: spring, maven, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I pulled the latest Spring Batch Admin-1.3.0-RELEASE and am trying to build and deploy. In eclipse I imported then as Maven Projects. I try to build with maven and it fails unless I remove these lines from the pom.xml files.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.springsource.bundlor</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.bundlor.maven</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

or else I get an error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.springsource.bundlor:com.springsource.bundlor.maven:1.0.0.RELEASE:bundlor (bundlor-transform) on project spring-batch-admin-resources: Execution bundlor-transform of goal com.springsource.bundlor:com.springsource.bundlor.maven:1.0.0.RELEASE:bundlor failed: Plugin com.springsource.bundlor:com.springsource.bundlor.maven:1.0.0.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.objectweb.asm:com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm.tree:jar:3.1.0, org.objectweb.asm:com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm.commons:jar:3.1.0, org.objectweb.asm:com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm:jar:3.1.0: Could not find artifact org.objectweb.asm:com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm.tree:jar:3.1.0 in internal-repository (http://nexus-server:8082/nexus/content/groups/released) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add spring repositories in your pom.xml to tell maven to look there as well while looking up for dependencies [as mentioned here](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/faq#q8)